# Manage Multiple Login page with Spring authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is this possible to manage multiple login page with spring authorization server?

Suppose, we have 2 client and both client want a different login page

client 1 need /login url

client 2 need /login2 url..

Comment: I am curious why do you need such feature ? Is there any specific use case ?

Comment: @Paras we need multiple page cause we need to show some different image or logo as per the client.

Comment: You can actually store these as attributes to RegisteredClient and then use those values to customize the login page. That's how it is done everywhere.

Comment: @Paras Do you have any example how may i achieve what you explain?

Comment: You are referring to : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server ? Right ?

Comment: @Paras First i refer this project but it is not contains what i actually want.

Comment: I meant when you say `spring authorization server` - you are talking about the same project ? Right ? Not `spring-security-oauth2`. They both provide authorization server. `spring-authorization-server` is new while `spring-security-oauth2` is near end support this May.

Comment: @Paras yes i am talking about the spring-authorization-server. but i meant to say how to use multiple login page with multiple client with the help of spring-authorization-server?
Or how to add attributes with client? How to do that i don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is how to brand a login page based on the current `clientId`. We can use any technique available in Spring Security, as it is fully available and not hidden when using Spring Authorization Server.

As you point out, one way to handle this would be to perform a custom redirect when authentication is required. This would be handled in a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. You can build a delegate with a mapping of clientIds to login urls. Normally, I'd encourage you to try it yourself (learning new things is fun, right!?), but in this case, here's an example:

```java
public class BrandedAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private final Map<String, AuthenticationEntryPoint> authenticationEntryPoints;
    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint defaultEntryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");

    public BrandedAuthenticationEntryPoint(Map<String, String> loginUrls) {
        Map<String, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map = new HashMap<>();
        loginUrls.forEach((clientId, loginUrl) ->
                map.put(clientId, new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginUrl)));
        this.authenticationEntryPoints = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        AuthenticationEntryPoint delegate = this.defaultEntryPoint;

        // Attempt to resolve a specific login url based on clientId
        String clientId = request.getParameter("clientId");
        if (clientId != null) {
            delegate = this.authenticationEntryPoints.getOrDefault(clientId, this.defaultEntryPoint);
        }

        delegate.commence(request, response, authException);
    }
}
```

SAS and Form Login are two different filter chains in the default sample, so you would apply this in the normal way on both filter chains:

```java
http.exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new BrandedAuthenticationEntryPoint(...))
);
```

More information on [AuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authenticationentrypoint) is available in the reference docs.